# Bash: How to transfer file from local path to SSH server?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh, terminal

What does one have to write to copy a file from a local location, to a password-protected remote ssh server in a terminal/bash script using Linux?

For example:

Source:  /home/bin/file.txt

Destination: user@server.com

Comment: `scp  /home/bin/file.txt user@server.com:`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SCP is designed to do this. Using your example:

```
$ scp /home/bin/file.txt user@server.com:/path/to/store
```

If you want it scripted w/o requiring a password, you'll want to setup SSH keys for the user the script is running as.  Digital Ocean has a good tutorial on how to setup SSH keys located here: [How To Set Up SSH Keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)